# Can someone explain what is wrong in my memory pool?

Tags: c, memory-management, glibc

I compiled in C with -O3 and as share library on Linux Fedora x64. I used some mallocs after one. It seems when I work with wmemcpy and other functions in this family the change in one memory makes change in other...
I may violate size of memory? Or the problem is in my implementation?

Thanks in advance!

```
char* ur_free_available(struct memory_pool* pool, uint64_t sz)
{
    uint64_t size =  sz + sizeof(struct _MyPage);
    if(pool->free_pos > 0)
    {
        if(pool->free_blocks[pool->free_pos - 1].pNext - pool->free_blocks[0].pNext > size)
        {
            uint64_t i, j;
            char *addr;
            struct _MyPage mpg;
            for(i = 1; i < pool->free_pos; ++i)
            {
                if(pool->free_blocks[i].pNext - pool->free_blocks[0].pNext > size)
                {
                    mpg.pPrev = NULL;
                    mpg.pNext = pool->free_blocks[i-1].pNext;
                    break;
                }

            }
            pool->free_blocks[0].pPrev = NULL;
            for(j = i; j < pool->free_pos; ++j)
            {                   
                    if(j > 0)
                        pool->free_blocks[j-i].pPrev = pool->free_blocks[j-1].pPrev;
                    pool->free_blocks[j-i].pNext = pool->free_blocks[j].pNext;                                      
            }
            pool->free_pos -= i;
            pool->free_pos++;
            memcpy(addr,(char*)&mpg, sizeof(mpg));
            return &addr[0] + sizeof(struct _MyPage);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}


char* ur_mem_alloc(struct memory_pool* pool, uint64_t sz)
{
    char *addr;
    struct _MyPage mpg;
    uint64_t size = sz  + sizeof(mpg);
    uint64_t j = 0, c, op;
    if(pool->init_pos_is != 7)
    {
        //bzero(pool, sizeof(pool));        
        pool->init_pos_is = 7;
        pool->free_pos = 0;
        pool->hp_position = 0;
        pool->st_position = 0;
        mpg.pPrev = NULL;   
        for(c = 0; c < HP_CNT; c++)
            pool->_extramem[c] = NULL;
        pool->free_blocks[0].pNext = NULL;
        //pool->_bytes = malloc(ST_MYPAGE_NO*ST_MYPAGE_SIZE);
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&llk1);
        _mpool = pool;
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&llk1);
        atexit(equit);
    }

    if((addr = ur_free_available(pool, size)) != NULL)      
    {
        return &addr[0];
    }
    op = pool->hp_position;
    if(size + (ST_MYPAGE_SIZE * pool->st_position) > ST_MYPAGE_NO * ST_MYPAGE_SIZE)
    {
        uint64_t i;     
        for(i = 0; i < HP_CNT; ++i)
        {
            if(size < (pow(8, i)-pool->hp_position)*HP_MYPAGE_SIZE)             
            {
                j = i;              


                if(pool->_extramem[i] == NULL)
                {       
                    pool->hp_position = 0;  
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&llk2);
                    pool->_extramem[i] = (char*)malloc((uint64_t)pow(8, i) * HP_MYPAGE_SIZE);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&llk2);
                }
                break;          
            }

        }

        addr = &pool->_extramem[j][pool->hp_position*HP_MYPAGE_SIZE];
        mpg.pPrev = (struct _MyPage*)&pool->_extramem[j][op*HP_MYPAGE_SIZE];
        //printf("j %u %u %u\n", j, (uint64_t)size, (uint64_t)(pow(8, i-1))*HP_MYPAGE_SIZE);
        pool->hp_position += floor(size/HP_MYPAGE_SIZE) + 1;        
        mpg.pNext = (struct _MyPage*)&pool->_extramem[j][pool->hp_position*HP_MYPAGE_SIZE];

        memcpy(addr,(char*)&mpg, sizeof(mpg));
        return &addr[0] + sizeof(struct _MyPage);
        //
    }
    else
    {
        if(pool->st_position != 0)
        {
            mpg.pPrev = (struct _MyPage*)&pool->_extramem[j][(pool->hp_position)];
        }
        mpg.pNext = NULL;
        pool->st_position += floor(size/ST_MYPAGE_SIZE);
        addr = &pool->_bytes[(uint64_t)(pool->st_position-floor(size/ST_MYPAGE_SIZE)) * ST_MYPAGE_SIZE];
        memcpy(addr,(char*)&mpg, sizeof(mpg));
        return &addr[0] + sizeof(struct _MyPage);
    }

}
void ur_mem_free(struct memory_pool* pool, char *addr)
{
    if(addr == NULL) return;

    pool->free_blocks[pool->free_pos].pPrev = pool->free_blocks[pool->free_pos].pNext;
    pool->free_blocks[pool->free_pos].pNext = (struct _MyPage*)(addr - sizeof(struct _MyPage));
    pool->free_pos++;
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with your implementation?

Comment: don't call malloc a lot... (and faster memory use stack when is not full)

Comment: Is the malloc's performance already a bottleneck? What makes you think that you can freely interpret the pointers returned by malloc as a pointers to a single contiguous block of memory that is all available to you (I mean your trickery inside the ur_free_available function)? Did you check the implementation of malloc in glibc's sources?

Comment: If I can't use continuously, so how to use the memory back by malloc? Performance, also, it is not reentrant. So I decided not to call it many times.

Comment: You may not touch(write) memory before the pointer returned by malloc and you may not write memory past (ptr+size). If you really have problems with reentrancy then you can of course preallocate as many chunks of memory as you need and keep a list of free chunks, but you should not manipulate the chunks the way you do. So, for example, you have to pick the first chunk that has enough room and return it. Also, you still call malloc if your free list is empty - this may cause reentrancy problems.

Comment: As the last note on your current implementation - you increment the requested size twice - upon entry into ur_mem_alloc and then into ur_free_available. But why do you think you have reentrancy problems?

Comment: I think problem is in use of memory arithmetic with wchar_t family function, I used malloc, but less, and it worked most part, shall do rest later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breafly looking into function `ur_free_available`, the variable `addr` is not initialized, but you memcpy to it corrupting a random memory region. Then you try to return something using the same non-initialized pointer.